# Can Raven Db run on Winhost?

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to run Raven Db in embeddedmode  on Winhost, but I get a securityexception with following stacktrace:

```
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties() +53
   Raven.Database.Util.PortUtil.FindPort() in PortUtil.cs:34
   Raven.Database.Util.PortUtil.GetPort(String portStr) in PortUtil.cs:17
   Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration.Initialize() in InMemoryRavenConfiguration.cs:109
   Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration.LoadConfigurationAndInitialize(IEnumerable`1 values) in RavenConfiguration.cs:30
   Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration..ctor() in RavenConfiguration.cs:19
   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.get_Configuration() in EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:45
   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.set_DataDirectory(String value) in EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:69
   StingyPrice.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs:42
```

My application is running in full trust (internal) mode but judging from that exception I'm making a bold assumption that Raven will never run unless they loosen their security policies.

Am I wrong or is it possible to run Raven Db at Winhost?
Also if it's not possible, a list of shared web hosting providers that can run Raven Db would be much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Did you get it working?

Comment: Nope, I guess I just assumed that it would not work. I started running EC2 micro instance instead. At least there I get full control of everything and no problems running a site with raven there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [www.winhost.com](http://www.winhost.com/a/leniel_l_1) as described here:

[How can I run RavenDB in a shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376839/114029)

It has the so desired **Full Trust Allowed** which is something one should look for in the case of RavenDB to avoid the current security permissions problems...

**NOTE:** I just tried this host and can confirm that it works great with RavenDB in Full Trust... :-)

Answer (score 2):

RavenDB requires full trust to run in server / embedded mode.

Comment: I'm running my app on full trust and  Raven in embedded mode but does Raven always call Raven.Database.Util.PortUtil.FindPort()? Because I have  UseEmbeddedHttpServer option off and still I get that FindPort() call.

Comment: @Ayende: do you really need the call to FindPort() when using the embedded store? I also thought that setting `UseEmbeddedHttpServer = false` would let me get rid of this security exception... but it's not the case. The code still calls that method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run RavenDB on Winhost.  You will need to change the `web.config` file, set the correct `Raven/WorkingDir` and enable Full trust.

When running, you will get an error regarding WebSockets. You can open up a support ticket to have it enabled and have “Overlapped Recycle” disabled.

I (employee of Winhost) wrote an [official startup guide here](http://blog.winhost.com/getting-started-with-ravendb/) if you want to try out RavenDb on Winhost.

Comment: You wouldn't have happened to write a similar guide in regards to MSSQL and using Entity Framework using Code First, possibly? Or know about such a resource.