# Shared hosting providers supporting RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting, ravendb, cloud-hosting, appharbor

I setup an AppHarbor application only to find out that it does not support embedded RavenDB.  It looks like it may be coming soon to [AppHarbor](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/6f0af8b78f5d0d16/6e2c30e31e7ae80f?lnk=gst&q=appharbor). In the mean time, all it does is throw an error as shown [here](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/issues/400).

Does anyone have any recommendations for shared hosting providers that support RavenDB? I am working on a small project, so free would be awesome (*which is why I looked towards AppHarbor*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [www.winhost.com](http://www.winhost.com/a/leniel_l_1) as described here:

[How can I run RavenDB in a shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376839/114029)

It has the so desired **Full Trust Allowed** which is something one should look for in the case of RavenDB to avoid the current security permissions problems...

**NOTE:** I just tried this host and can confirm that it works great with RavenDB in Full Trust... :-)

Comment: Thanks @Leniel. In searching for PaaS providers like AppHarbor, I found out about http://www.ironfoundry.org/. They too support embedded RavenDB.

Answer (score 12):

[AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) now has a [great RavenDB add-on](https://appharbor.com/addons/ravenhq) from the guys at [RavenHQ](https://ravenhq.com/).

Comment: amazing... I've been waiting for that! Thank you.

Comment: [CloudBird](https://www.cloudbird.net) also offer RavenDB hosting and have an AppHarbor [AddOn](https://appharbor.com/addons/cloudbird) as well

Answer (score 2):

I have already reported and discussed the issue on the RavenDB mailing list (hint).

http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/af98f98a35289ad1/f9e040d8acfd0c72

You do understand that every deploy (and even possibly between deploys) that your data will be wiped/reverted to the source control version?

If that is fine and the data set is small, run RavenDB in-memory mode and seed the data to it.

Else as you mention RavenNest (hosted RavenDB for AppHarbor) is coming soon, Ayende and team are testing it internally I last heard.

Comment: Thank @Phil. I've joined the mailing list. I wasn't aware that the data would be wiped on a new deploy. I hope RavenNest would be coming sooner than later.

Comment: @AdamSpicer it looks like it will be coming on the sooner side, given that they ran a design contest in October http://99designs.com/web-design/contests/website-design-wanted-raven-nest-98775

Comment: @Phil, so from your google post I gather that you are using an _in memory_ option instead of persisting the data to disk? I didn't realize that was an option. I do need to persist my data though. Are you aware of a reliable hosting provider that supports presisting RavenDB data?

Comment: @AdamSpicer you would have to look at shared hosting, a VPS, dedicated server or Amazon EC2/Azure. Personally, I'm not a great sysadmin and am still learning RavenDB so I'm waiting on RavenNest but I use a VPS and run RavenDB as a service.