# Cloud Service Providers for RavenDb

Tags: database, web-services, ravendb, cloud-hosting, appharbor

Not to be confused with [Shared hosting providers supporting RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997054/shared-hosting-providers-supporting-ravendb) or other similar questions. I do not need a web host, nor want to deploy RavenDb in *Embedded* or *Web Site* mode...

**Question:** Are there any cloud service providers for RavenDB, like [MongoHQ](http://mongohq.com) and [MongoLab](http://mongolab.com) for the MongoDB platform?

**Edit:** [RavenHQ](http://ravenhq.com) and [Cloudbird](http://cloudbird.net) are two providers, but they are not in production - answers should only include those that are currently available.

Comment: It looks like http://ravenhq.com intends to do this, but it is not in production yet.

Comment: it's LIVE now blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/17/hosted-ravendb-on-appharbor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of searching, conversations with RavenDB folks on Jabbr.net and speaking to some provider companies we have a answer:

[RavenHQ.com](http://ravenhq.com) and [Cloudbird.net](http://cloudbird.net) provide such services. RavenHQ is ready for production and in the US East zone, while Cloudbird is in beta and in the EU West zone.

Comment: [CloudBird](https://www.cloudbird.net) is now out of Beta and hosting production databases in the EU

Comment: Update: CloudBird has unfortunately shut down, so there's only RavenHQ left.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ravenhq.com should be live any day as Ayende mentioned in the latest RavenDb videos on tekpub

**UPDATE**

RavenHq is now live on AppHarbor
http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/17/hosted-ravendb-on-appharbor

Comment: Tekpub's videos are paid for, can you provide any documentation of their "go live" date? I could not find any.

Comment: Nothing's promised but I can tell you this: we have a project under development that will be released in a month and we chose RavenDb because we believe its "almost there" according to @Ayende's tweets

Comment: Afraid, I've been waiting since November for RavenHQ (used to be called RavenNest?), seems to be closer now though as they have a website up.

Comment: @Phil it's LIVE now http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/17/hosted-ravendb-on-appharbor

Comment: Yes, I've seen it via twitter :)

Comment: Beta... and you can only sign up on an app harbor account, not via their website.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cloudbird.net/ I've seen this mentioned but same as http://www.ravenhq.com/ they don't give much detail. I also don't know who the authors of cloudbird are.

Otherwise, you could just use an EC2/Azure to host it? (I've seen Azure and RavenDB talked about on Twitter, there is some github projects with instructions)

Comment: I'll check out cloudbird and the EC2 idea though I doubt its free

Comment: RavenHQ will only have a tiny amount of space free. Plus you get a year of stuff free with Azure/EC2. To answer your edit of "only live" the answer is none. I've extensively looked.

Comment: you use jabbr? I think we have been talking there in the RavenDB room.

Comment: Haven't been on it in a few days, name on there is the same as here (and is also my twitter username, I respond to quite a few questions on there)

Comment: It's live on app harbor http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/17/hosted-ravendb-on-appharbor