# RavenDB EmbeddedDocumentStorage in Medium Trust

Tags: ravendb, embedded-database, medium-trust

I'm trying to use RavenDB in Medium Trust, I would like to try the embedded model, since the hosting (cheap) I use will not allow to install a service. My code to initialize is the following:

```
private void ConfigureStorage()
    {
        store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
        store.Configuration.DefaultStorageTypeName = "munin";
        store.Configuration.DataDirectory=Server.MapPath("$/App_Data");
        store.Initialize();
    }
```

that works in full trust, but in Medium it throws:

**Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**
with the following stack trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.DemandPermission(IntPtr pNMD) +0
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NativeMethods.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MEMORYSTATUSEX& lpBuffer) +0
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.InternalMemoryStatus.Refresh() +68
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.InternalMemoryStatus.get_TotalPhysicalMemory() +11
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.get_TotalPhysicalMemory() +49
   Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration.GetDefaultMemoryCacheLimitMegabytes() +301
   Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration.Initialize() +631
   Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration.LoadConfigurationAndInitialize(IEnumerable`1 values) +311
   Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration..ctor() +189
   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.get_Configuration() +99
   Wine2.MvcApplication.ConfigureStorage() +84
   Wine2.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +84
```

Raven build is: **Version 573**

Are there some workaraound to make it working under medium trust, or is this scenario unsupported?

Comment: I'd try again with 616, I remember seeing Ayende saying he fixed some medium trusts issues in the past week. Also why munin?

Comment: @Phil thanks for help: Isn't munin the only available option in medium trust ?

Comment: This is also my doubt when contracting a hosting company... I asked them for a free period just to test and see if things work as expected! :] They'll get back. I hope they allow me to test it before contracting a plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under strict medium trust, RavenDB won't work.
But there plenty of hosting companies that provide hosting where RavenDB does work, because they tweaked the permissions.

Comment: It would be nice to know the way they tweak, BTW build 616 seems to be compilew w/o AllowPartiallyTrustedCaller

Comment: Well... I'm having this same problem in Medium Trust. I even tried the latest unstable build 1.0.638 of the embedded store. Same thing. :( To see the exception I get just access the site: http://schetine.siteprofissional.com/ Any thoughts Ayende? No way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience I just gave up trying to run the embedded store in **Medium Trust**. I was getting the same error described in your question.

To overcome this, you can try [www.winhost.com](http://www.winhost.com/a/leniel_l_1) as described here:

[How can I run RavenDB in a shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376839/114029)

It has the so desired **Full Trust Allowed** which is something one should look for in the case of RavenDB to avoid the current security permissions problems...

**NOTE:** I just tried this host and can confirm that it works great with RavenDB in Full Trust... :-)

Comment: The .NET web team is no longer supporting medium trust... so MVC as a whole might break. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause

Comment: @EricRohlfs nice to know about this! :) Thanks for sharing the link.